# Inserting an image into excel.activex.image control at runtime with vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I've tried many examples with various adjustments, but get a hresult type mismatch error. Plea e help. Im trying to develop an excel report that includes images from a database. I'm using office 2007 & vbexpress.net

Xlsheet.image1.picture=image.fromfile (imagepath)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to add a picture to an excel sheet, this will do it.

```
      xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\yourpic.JPG", _
         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, _
         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45)
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please be more specific in your question (and even possibly post code of what you have tried).